# MacOs Sierra breaks Network Configs

Tags: networking, macos, macos-sierra

After updating from macOS Mavericks to Sierra, two major problems appeared on my networks configs:

- I cannot connect to a particular network anymore, the eduroam one. The "insert your user and password" windows keeps prompting after inputing the data. The password is correct, which is even weirder. Before the update there were no issues.
- I cannot connect to one particular domain, at least. The browser will not load it. If I ping, i get one response, but the rest of segments return timeout

  > PING www.fbi.h-da.de (141.100.59.172): 56 data bytes
  >
  > Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
  >
  > Request timeout for icmp_seq 1

How is this possible? The second issue is particularly confusing: how can only one domain be affected?

Comment: I don't know about the basic problem, but `ping` isn't telling you anything relevant -- I tried `ping www.fbi.h-da.de` from my computer (with a working, relatively open Internet connection) and got the same result. It looks like www.fbi.h-da.de is either behind a firewall or configured not to respond to pings.